# Populate Hash with each key and value from pg object

Tags: ruby

could you help me I am not getting out of this, I am trying to get the returns straight to my hash but I need to perform insertion of three pgcon objects below my code.

i try with each.

I tried with two each but the variable if called outside has only 1 value and not all records.

```
@bd_local = {}
@bd_remote = {}
@c_local = PG.connect(:hostaddr => '10.11.12.36', :port => 5432, :dbname => "cnet", :user => "cuser", :connect_timeout => 90)

#get adress from local bd to acess remote bd
@bdlocal_ip_remote.each do |k|
  @ips = {}
  @ips = k

#conect in remote servers
  @c_remote = PG.connect(:hostaddr => @ips["host"], :port => 5432, :dbname => "cdbs", :user => "cnet", :connect_timeout => 90)

#GET ALL DATA and set to hash @bd_remote
  @bd_remote = @c_remote.exec("SELECT id,name,phone_number,active FROM trunks")
    @bd_remote.each do |q|
    @ipx = {}
    @ipx = q
  #puts "Server: #{@ips["host"]} - ID: #{@ipx["id"]} - Phone: - #{@ipx["phone"]} - Status #{@ipx["active"]}"
  end
end
```

I get 74 records when I perform this way.

but running outside of each I have only the first record of one of the remote servers.

I need to access all 74 records that were obtained by each in a hash outside of each to start a hash comparison process but I can't.

> Example: puts bd_remote["id"]
>
> id=1 id=2 id=3 id=4 id=5 and others... from outside each to execute hash compare.

Comment: `@ipx = q` Looks like you're overwriting `@ipx` each time a new record loads

Comment: What you probably want is to initialize `@ipx` outside the loops and then add a new element into `@ipx` in each iteration of the `#each` loop

Comment: exactly! but even initializing it from outside only prints a single value;

Comment: I'm not sure how you plan on storing the values in a hash. For each record from the database, whats the key and whats the value? Where in your code do you add the key/value pair to the `@ipx` hash? Where exactly did you initialize the `@ipx` hash? Outside both loops? Where are you printing the values of `@ipx` so it only shows 1 record? What you're saying doesn't match the code you posted

Comment: #GET ALL DATA and set to hash @bd_remote
  bd_remote = @c_remote.exec("SELECT id,name,phone_number,active FROM trunks")

Comment: bd_remote.each do |q| ipx = q